# Facebook Story for my app: Unable to generate story

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

In the Open Graph Dashboard of my Facebook application I get error for my story saying "Unable to generate story" after creating both custom or storys with standard object.

So under the page facebookdeveloper/apps/myapp/story/openGraph where I usually have nice storys for different scenarios (one on one, multiple people, past tence) it just says error "Unable to generat story" everywhere.

My story titles says for example: "Mr X read a book.title on myApp" and then "Unable..."

There is no more information on why I get the error. 
I had storys with similiar object etc. for the application previously which I removed. Cant his affect the creation of new stories?

Anyone else who has the same problem and a solution?

Answer (score 5):

I had "Unable to generate story" until I completed the steps at : 
[Facebook Open Graph Story](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/)

- Setup the Backend Server (just put the PHP example on a server you can access)
- Test it using the Object Debugger
- (Once you resolve any errors from Debugger) Publish a test action

OpenGraph can then generate the different scenario stories.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try clicking on Manage Sample Data, create the sample object first, then the sample action. Setup the sample action to use the sample object you just created. This worked for me, just in time to stop me going mad. I got this solution from a Japanese site : http://konifar.com/1185

Answer (score 2):

This error comes up because facebook has no examples of the story to render.  It does not inhibit your ability to post the actions.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too late to provide an answer but it will be helpful to others who are having the same issue,I was having the same issue and it held me back by a couple of hours after one successful post you will be able to get the preview until then you can't get a preview.

Answer (score 0):

Another point when publishing a test action:

- It needs to be from your account, so if you have an account just for testing that's not the same as the admin account, it won't work
- It can't be from a test user - I think this is related to the first point